# Manually override column cells left/right padding dont work

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Demo is found at `link remvoed` and using jqgrid version 4.9.2

In there you'll find I made a link reference to seperate CSS file at https://dealerapp-dev.bookitout.com/Member/Css/jqgrid-v4.9.2/ui.jqgrid-bio-extended.css

In that file, I override the default left/right padding found at `ui.jqgrid.css`, changed it from `2px` to `15px` in `ui.jqgrid-bio-extended.css`

The left padding works great but right padding is hidden (or chopped off).

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow > td { padding: 0 15px 0 15px; }
```

How to have it not be chopped off instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all one can see that the width of the column is not optimal after auto-resizing. The problem exist because `getAutoResizableWidth` method used during calculation of the optimal size suppose that the padding of all rows is *the same*. There are exist the first row of the width 0px which have class `jqgfirstrow` instead of the class `jqgrow` used in other rows with data. To fix the problem you should adjust `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgfirstrow > td` too

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgfirstrow > td { padding: 0 15px 0 15px; }
```

I would recommend you to use the following more common CSS rule:

```css
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgfirstrow > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqfoot > td,
.ui-jqgrid tr.footrow > td {
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}
```

and to consider to increase the padding of column headers additionally:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr {
    margin: -2px -15px -2px 0;
}
```

About chopping off the text in the cells there are exist a misunderstanding of `padding` in my opinion. The text not have to be cut off. I don't know CSS good enough, but I can suggest you to place the content of every cell inside of `<div>` which have CSS property `overflow: hidden`. It will follow the cutting of the content in the case. The corresponding code

```js
$("#" + _jqgridSpreadsheetId).bind("jqGridAfterLoadComplete jqGridAfterAddRow", function () {
    $(this).find("tr.jqgrow>td").wrapInner("<div style='overflow: hidden;'></div>");
});
```

will reduce the performance of the grid, but it will make chopping off the texts like you want. It's recommended to add the code **before** the grid will be created. Only in the case you will be sure that the code will work on the first loading of the grid.

The last remark. You should add `jquery-2.0.3.min.map` and in the same folder where you have `jquery-v2.0.3.min.js`, because comment `//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-2.0.3.min.map` exist in the `jquery-v2.0.3.min.js`. In the same way `jquery-2.0.3.min.map` contains typically `"sources":["jquery-2.0.3.js"]` and so you should include non-compressed file `jquery-2.0.3.js` too. Currently loading of you demo in debugger produces the following error message in the console:

> HTTP404: NICHT GEFUNDEN: Der Server hat keine Übereinstimmungen für
>   den angeforderten URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) gefunden. (XHR):
>   GET -
>   https://dealerapp-dev.bookitout.com/Member/Scripts/jquery-v2.0.3/jquery-2.0.3.min.map

Comment: Oleg: That's suck on the jquery map file.  I renamed jquery files 4 years ago & didn't see the error.  All fixed now.  The column cell padding works great now.  That's a lot of CSS class-names.  :-)  Not going to chop off text on this one.  Thanks again.

Comment: In 3-6 months, I'm going to start migrating over ASP.NET GridView to jqGrid v4.9.2 (junking WebForm for Razor/Controller).  Curious, will it a while before you start working on jqGrid v4.10 enhancement, like 2 years  later or something?  Just wondering because I have 2 webpages using jqGrid v4.5 with lots of ugly hacks (thanks to Tony) & don't want to migrate them two over yet.